# Результат tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Функция ***askopenfilenames()*** возвращает список выбранных файлов с их полными
путями, а мне надо только имена файлов без путей. Может существует какой-нибудь параметр для этой цели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ещё попробовать через `os.path.basename` создать список из наименований файлов:

```python
import os

# ...

filepaths = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
filenames = list(map(os.path.basename, filepaths))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто я думал, что есть какой-то параметр у askopenfilenames, который я не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться  filein.name для получения имени файла.